# Firebase getting values from database in a fragment

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help with my code. I couldn't solve the problem. I'm making debug with logs. One of them inside of onDataChange() method `Log.i("SELFIES", image_name);` and other two are `Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", String.valueOf(mPhotoIds.size()));` out of this method.

The problem is, it doesn't get into onDataChange method initially, passes over it, prints array's size, returns view. After that it comes back and get into method and prints the fetched data, then finishes (My aim is to use mPhotoIds array in other method but this problem occurs).

The debugger console output:

```
    I/SELFIEFRAGMENT: Array size is : 0
    I/SELFIEFRAGMENT: Array size is : 0
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 998 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    I/SELFIES: asdasd_giris_25.54.47_29.Mayıs.2019
    I/SELFIES: fdsafdas_giris_25.55.4_29.Mayıs.2019
    I/SELFIES: sdf_cikis_8.44.32_30.Mayıs.2019
```

My code:

```
package com.newstrange.worklog;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListSelfiesFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseStorage mStorageIns;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabaseIns;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mDatabaseIns = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); // DATABASE

        mStorageIns = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(); // STORAGE

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_selfies, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.selfies_recyclerview);

        //initialize lists
        final ArrayList<String> mPhotoIds = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<Bitmap> mPhotoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get names
        DatabaseReference usersPhotoRef = mDatabaseIns.getReference().child("storeIDs");

        usersPhotoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String image_name = uniqueKeySnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.i("SELFIES", image_name); // PRINTING when everything is finished
                    mPhotoIds.add(image_name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", "Array size is : " +mPhotoIds.size()); // PRINTS 0

        if (!mPhotoIds.isEmpty()) {
            final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
            for (int i = 0; i < mPhotoIds.size(); i++) {

                StorageReference photoRef = mStorageIns.getReference().child("images/" + mPhotoIds.get(i) + ".png");

//                    final File localFile = File.createTempFile(mPhotoIds.get(i), "png"); // içine yüklenecek değişken
                photoRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        mPhotoArrayList.add(bitmap);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", e.getMessage());

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        SelfiesAdapter selfiesAdapter = new SelfiesAdapter(getActivity(), mPhotoArrayList, mPhotoIds);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(selfiesAdapter);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", "Array size is : " + mPhotoIds.size()); // PRINTS 0
        // PRINTS 0

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your Firebase storage function just after your for loop of `onDataChange`

```
//initialize lists
        final ArrayList<String> mPhotoIds = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<Bitmap> mPhotoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get names
        DatabaseReference usersPhotoRef = mDatabaseIns.getReference().child("storeIDs");

        usersPhotoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String image_name = uniqueKeySnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.i("SELFIES", image_name); // PRINTING when everything is finished
                    mPhotoIds.add(image_name);
                }

          if (!mPhotoIds.isEmpty()) {
                final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
                for (int i = 0; i < mPhotoIds.size(); i++) {

                StorageReference photoRef = mStorageIns.getReference().child("images/" + mPhotoIds.get(i) + ".png");

    //                    final File localFile = File.createTempFile(mPhotoIds.get(i), "png"); // içine yüklenecek değişken
                photoRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        mPhotoArrayList.add(bitmap);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", e.getMessage());

                    }
                });
             }
         }

          SelfiesAdapter selfiesAdapter = new SelfiesAdapter(getActivity(), mPhotoArrayList, mPhotoIds);
          mRecyclerView.setAdapter(selfiesAdapter);

          mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
          mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
          mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

         Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", "Array size is : " + mPhotoIds.size()); // PRINTS 0

     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.i("SELFIEFRAGMENT", databaseError.getMessage());
     }
 });
```